PHP Shell_exec() Возвращает null
Присутствует простой python файл, который возвращает True. В php скрипте вызывается функция shell_exe('python path/to/file/test.py'), команда возвращает null, при том что если ввести простую команду, например shell_exec('echo test') то она выполнится. В powerShell все нормально выполняется, работаю в Laravel 10.

Для начала надо пояснить, что такое это "True", которое возвращает питон. Что конкретно печатает этот скрипт в терминале? Строка "True" или что?
